# php code not redirecting to ajax calls

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have following js code, which is validating a form calling a php script at backend:

```
$(function() {

    // Setup form validation on the #register-form element
    $("#register_form").validate({

        // Specify the validation rules
        rules: {
            register_username: "required",
            register_password: "required",
            register_email: {
                required: true,
                register_email: true
            },
            register_confirm_password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
        },

        // Specify the validation error messages
        messages: {
            register_username: "Please enter your username",
            register_password: "Please enter your password",
            register_confirm_password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
            },
            register_email: "Please enter a valid email address",
        },

       submitHandler(function(form) {
            $.ajax({  
              type: 'POST',
              url: $(this).attr('action'),
              data: $(this).serialize(),
              dataType : 'json',
              success(function(data) {
                if (data){
                    alert("success");
                    // $(this)[0].reset();
                }
              })
            });
            return false;
        });
    });

});
```

At the backend I have following code:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

The issue is in browser, I am successfully able to dump php data, but unable to call this function message in js:

```
submitHandler(function(form) {
    $.ajax({  
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType : 'json',
        success(function(data) {
            if (data) {
                alert("success");
                // $(this)[0].reset();
            }
        })
    });
    return false;
});
```

Please help me to solve the above code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `var_dump($_POST);` wont output valid JSON. Change it to this:

`echo json_encode($_POST);`

Comment: thank you for the help. So, we need to put valid json as output.

Comment: @learner Yes, since in your `submitHandler` you have `dataType : 'json'`.

Comment: But still I am unable to get response in js file.

Comment: @learner Check with dev console that there aren't any warnings etc coming from the PHP script. If there's anything more than the valid JSON string, you simply wont get anything in your success handler.